# Python http server does not conform to ATS policy

Tags: python, swift, http, ssl, https

I created a http server in python that works as intended (responses a json as string) and a `URLSession` in Swift that's supposed to retrieve that json. My problem is that Apple requires the HTTP connections to use HTTPS.

> **App Transport Security (ATS)**
>
> Starting in iOS 9.0 and OS X 10.11, a new security feature called App Transport Security (ATS) is enabled by default for all HTTP connections made with URLSession. ATS requires that HTTP connections use HTTPS (RFC 2818).
>   For more information, see NSAppTransportSecurity in the Information Property List Key Reference.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession

This is the code for my python server:

```py
import http.server
import ssl
import json

class RequestHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self.set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({
            'title': 'title'
        }).encode())

port = 8888
host = ''

with http.server.HTTPServer((host, port), RequestHandler) as httpd:
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True)
    print('server serves on {}:{}'.format(host, port))
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Thats the command I used to generate the cert and key files: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`. When I start the python server file it requires me to enter the PEM pass phrase so I am assuming that worked.

And this is my Swift code for the `URLSession`:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8888")!
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error != nil else {
        print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    guard data != nil else {
        print("no data")
        return
    }

    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
dataTask.resume()
```

When I run the Python code and then the Swift code, Xcode gives me an error and prints *no data*. The error: Cannot start load of Task ... <1> since it does not conform to ATS policy

Note that I want my python server to conform to the ATS policy and NOT add any Domain Exceptions or the `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` key to my info.plist.

PS: The `ssl` module and `ssl.wrap_socket(...` was an attempt to make my HTTP server conform to the ATS policy.

Comment: Are you actually using an HTTPS url? Or is that just an error in the question? `let url = URL(string: "https://localhost:8888")!`

Comment: When I use `"https://localhost:8888"` I get multiple errors: ATS failed system trust, Connection 1: system TLS, Connection 1: encountered, Task ... HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes and prints _no data_ again

Answer (score 1):

I actually like to use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this, it's super simple and free (there are paid versions though). From their website,

> ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public
>   internet over secure tunnels.

For instance, I run my django projects on localhost:8000 and run ngrok to create https/http urls for my iOS app to connect to instead of trying to connect to localhost:8000 directly. It takes like two seconds to set up and get going.

Comment: Unfortunately only Pro & Business plans may bind TLS tunnels. But good idea though